# Serializing a double with JsonSerializer results in JSON with lower precision .net 5.0

Tags: c#, formatting, rounding, .net-5

While upgrading from dotnet core 2.2 to dotnet 5.0 we experienced failing tests that depend on consistent serilaization of objects to generate a hash. I have tracked this down to the way the double type is serialized when passed to the JsonSerializer.Serialize method. During serialization we seem to be losing precision where a double is rounded to the next decimal point, but not every number is rounded.

For example

```
var d = 50.494329039350461;

var dAsText = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(d);

//Value of dAsText is 50.49432903935046
```

When we deserialize we get the origial number back but we need to act on serialized data to generate our hash. Why has this behaviour changed between frameworks, is it a bug or is it intended? Are there any settings we can change to restore the previous implementation (while remaining on .net 5 of course). The same behaviour can be seen with Newtonsoft Json (I have raised an issue with them as well)

The behavior seem consistent on Windows 10x64 and in a Lunix Docker image. This is running in Visual Studio 2019 (latest update)

The problem can also be seen with these number:

50.494328391915907
30.316339899700989
50.494128852095287

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the consequence of [Floating-Point Parsing and Formatting improvements in .NET Core 3.0](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/floating-point-parsing-and-formatting-improvements-in-net-core-3-0/). There are many changes so worth reading the article, but in particular:

> ToString(), ToString("G"), and ToString("R") will now return the
> shortest roundtrippable string

Not sure about System.Text.Json, but Newtonsoft Json uses "R" specifier when writing double (and this makes sense). Using `d.ToString("R")` reproduces this issue.

Note that your number, and the number it serializes to, are actually equal:

```
var d =  50.494329039350461d;
var d2 = 50.49432903935046d;
var sameThing = d == d2; // true
bool sameBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(d).SequenceEqual(BitConverter.GetBytes(d2)); // true
```

So the last "1" digit is basically meaningless (due to `double` limited precision). As I understand from that article - now shortest roundtrippable value is returned, and `d2` is shortest indeed.

Article also says:

> For ToString("R"), there is no mechanism to fallback to the old
> behavior. The previous behavior would first try “G15” and then using
> the internal buffer would see if it roundtrips; if that failed, it
> would instead return “G17”.

And indeed using `d.ToString("G17")` returns the result you expect.

So, this is intended behaviour (previous behavior is considered a "bug" and fixed), and as far as I can tell - there are no settings to get back to previous behavior.

Comment: Thank you, I don't pretend that I fully understand the details of this but your description of the previous behaviour as a bug is enlightening. I guess our implementation of generating a has from the Json of an object is not ideal

Comment: I guess so, because those two numbers are the same, when represented with double, so they should better produce the same hash.